# Search the nth number of string in side the another list in python

Tags: python-3.x

add name, where  is a string denoting a contact name. This must store  as a new contact in the application.
find partial, where  is a string denoting a partial name to search the application for. It must count the number of contacts starting with  and print the count on a new line.
Given  sequential add and find operations, perform each operation in order.

```
Input:
4
add hack
add hackerrank
find hac
find hak

Sample Output
2
0

We perform the following sequence of operations:

1.Add a contact named hack.
2.Add a contact named hackerrank.
3.Find and print the number of contact names beginning with hac.
  There are currently two contact names in the application 
  and both of them start with hac, so we print 2 on a new line.
4.Find and print the number of contact names beginning with hak. 
  There are currently two contact names in the application
   but neither of them start with hak, so we print 0  on a new line.
```

i solved it but it is taking long time for large number of string. my code is

```
addlist =[]
findlist=[]
n = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(n):
    op, contact = input().strip().split(' ')
    if(op=='add'):
        addlist.append(contact)
    else:
        findlist.append(contact)
for item in findlist:
    count=0
    count=[count+1 for item2 in addlist if item in item2 if item==item2[0:len(item)]]
    print(sum(count))
```

is there any other way to avoid the long time to computation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as optimizing goes I broke your code apart a bit for readability and removed a redundant if statement. I'm not sure if its possible to optimize any further.

```
addlist =[]
findlist=[]

n = int(input().strip())

for a0 in range(n):
    op, contact = input().strip().split(' ')
    if(op=='add'):
        addlist.append(contact)
    else:
        findlist.append(contact)

for item in findlist:
    count = 0
    for item2 in addlist:
        if item == item2[0:len(item)]:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

I tested 10562 entries at once and it processed instantly so if it lags for you it can be blamed on your processor

Comment: Both are same thing. I just wanted to know,how     to reduce the multiple  iteration.

Comment: if we check for between 80000 to 100000

Comment: @Bishan Singh, I cant see any situation where you would need to process that much data but, if you're feeling crazy you could try and implement multi-threading and divide the load across a couple threads. that would increase the processing speed quite a bit for those insanely high numbers.

Comment: okay. thank you. But i am using that much data for your kind of information.I will see alternative way.Thanks for your time.